# How do I combine a Kafka Processor with a Kafka Streams application?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to construct a Kafka Streams operator that takes in a Stream< timestamp, data> and outputs another Stream where the timestamps are sorted in ascending order; the purpose is to deal with streams that have "out of order" entries due to delays in the supplier.

At first, I thought about doing this with time-windowed aggregation, but then I happened upon a solution using a Kafka Processor.  I figured I could then say something like:

```
class SortProcessor implements Processor<timestamp,data> ...
class SortProcessorSupplier ...supplies suitably initialized SortProcessor
KStream<timestamp,data> input_stream = ...sourced from "input_topic"
KStream<timestamp,data> output_stream =
        input_stream.process( new SortProcessorSupplier(...parameters...) );
```

However, this doesn't work because KStream.process returns `void`.

So, my question is:   How do I "wrap" the Processor so that I can use it as follows:

```
KStream<timestamp,data> input_stream = ...sourced from "input_topic"
KStream<timestamp,data> output_stream =
        new WrappedSortProcessor( input_stream, ...parameters... )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `Processor` you can use a [`Transformer`](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html), which is very similar to a `Processor` but is better suited to forwarding results on to the stream. You can then invoke it from the stream using the [`KStream.transform()`](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-) method instead of `process()`.